# Deployment of application to device failed Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to develope my first Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (Update 2). I've registered developer account and my phone, Lumia 635, is also activated. My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Both OS and Visual Studio are clean installed just few days ago. My phone is plugged into USB-port and I can see it in file explorer.

I've tried different USB-ports, not different USB-cable tho, also tried to google for solutions, no help.

I've followed exactly these orders to point where I am now:      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Code builds fine but when I try to deploy it comes this:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: firstapp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>Error: Value cannot be null.
```

I cannot emulate project either, it just shows Start in menu with green arrow, nothing more.

Is my best guess to reinstall everything and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it solved already. I'm not sure what actually fixed it, creating new WP 8.1 app project or installing some SDKs. Only thing matters is that its now working. :)